# Records not saved when updating OleDb

Tags: database, vb.net, oledb

I'm using the following code to update my records in the database:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

 Private Sub update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles updateBtn.Click

    '/// UPDATING TABLE - employee

    Try
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Employee.mdb;")
            conn.Open()
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE employee SET [Last_Name] = @lname, [First_Name]= @fname, MI = @mi, Bday = @bday, Age = @age, [Nationality] = @natio, [Contact_Number] = @contact, Sex = @gender, Address = @address, Department = @department, [Position] = @position, TIN = @tin, SSS = @sss, Pagibig = @pagibig, PhilHealth = @phh, Termi_Resi = @termiresi, [Date_hired] = @datehired, [Rate_Month] = @rm, [Date_End] = @dateTermiResi, Status = @status, [Father_Name] = @father, [Mother_Name] = @mother, Civil = @civil, Spouse = @spouse, [Number_of_Children] = @numberchild, Child1 = @child1, Child2 = @child2, Child3 = @child3, Child4 = @child4, Child5 = @child5, Child6 = @child6, Child7 = @child7, Child8 = @child8, Child9 = @child9 WHERE [EmployID] = @numberemp", conn)
            With command.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@numberemp", numberemp.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@lname", lname.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@fname", fname.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@mi", mi.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@bday", bday.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@age", age.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@natio", natio.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@contact", contact.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@gender", gender.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@address", address.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@department", department.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@position", position.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@tim", tin.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@sss", sss.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@pagibig", pagibig.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@phh", phh.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@termiresi", termiresi.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@datehired", datehired.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@rm", rm.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dateTermiResi", dateTermiResi.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@status", status.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@father", father.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@mother", mother.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@civil", civil.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@spouse", spouse.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@numberchild", numberchild.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child1", child1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child2", child2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child3", child3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child4", child4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child5", child5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child6", child6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child7", child7.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child8", child8.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child9", child9.Text)
            End With
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            command.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
            clearall()

            RefreshDGV()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Whenever I click the update button, it says

> Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!

but in the database, it's not. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: How do you know it isnt getting saved?  What do you do to know?  if `Dim rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery()` is non zero, it is getting saved and you have a different problem.  Also you should use `Add` so you can specify the type rather than `AddWithValue` and let OleDb guess what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the result of `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`. This will return the number of rows modified.

```
Dim rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
If rows = 0 then
    MessageBox.Show("No rows modified")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End If
```

If `rows = 0` then the problem is most likely with the `where` clause. In this case it's matching on the parameter.

```
.AddWithValue("@numberemp", numberemp.Text)
```

Try using

```
.AddWithValue("@numberemp", Integer.Parse(numberemp.Text))
```

To make sure it's the right type.

Also some database providers don't use the names you give for parameters. The only care about the order. So put `@numberemp` at the bottom of your parameter list as it's the last in the query.

Comment: Thanks! I placed `@numberemp` last in the parameters. Now my only problem is how to update all records in my five tables when selecting a row. I used `INNER JOIN` but it only shows two tables, so I separated the `Datagridviews` in the `TabControl`. I get the "No rows modified" when updating the second `Datagridview`. Thank you, sir :)